# Cannot build simple rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I created a task `lib/tasks/initiate.rake` with the code

```
namespace :initiate do
  desc "initiate bundle install"
  task :initiate do
    `bundle install`
  end
end
```

And I keep getting the following response:

```
$ rake initiate
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby22, which recognizes
warning: 2.2.3-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.2.1.
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'initiate'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What's going on?

Comment: What happens when you run `rake initiate:initiate` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `rake <namespace>:<task>`.

In your case that would be `rake initiate:initiate`

Answer (score 0):

You can run:

```
rake -T | grep initiate
```

To find out the proper namespace plus name you should be using to run that task.